# Keep Chrome open after terminating run in Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to keep the Chrome browser open after I terminate the run in Eclipse IDE.

Terminate refers to clicking the [Stop] icon.

[image]

I already tried adding detach in my ChromeOptions but the browser closes once terminated.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
...
options.addArguments("--detach");
...
dr = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Current workaround is to pause the execution so that I can use the browser, but the number of active terminal increases if I trigger and use newly generated browsers.

Another workaround is to not use **driver.quit**, but this is only applicable if I am able to predict where the error/issue is. And this does not seem to be a good practice.